# Assimilate existing apps?

Tags: integration, swt, osgi, rcp

I read all lot about rich client platforms and the OSGi framework, but stuck with this question: Is it possible to assimilate existing applications (either java-based or win32-based) in one application window?

I aim at connecting different kinds of (existing) application in one application (with Eclipse RCP) to offer the general window manager functionality (like resizing window, etc.) and additionally enhance it with inter-window communication or the like.

With SWT it is possible to write (kinda) native-looking applications and by using the OLE-Component I can integrate some functionality.  What I would really like to know is if I can assimilate the whole window and integrate it somewhere else?

Important points are...

1. visual integration and
2. listening methodologies...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an Eclipse based IBM product called [Lotus Expeditor](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/expeditor/) that does exactly this. If nothing else it's worth having a look at their datasheets, the trial code and the demos to get a feel for how it is implemented in the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can change external application's window style to WS_CHILD, and set it's parent to your main window. Also remember to call AttachThreadInput(), it will help your UI handle focusing more correctly. In any case you will probably encounter many problems while trying to make multiple windows work together. I'm not sure if it's even possible to eliminate all the problems.